# How to use TimePickerDialog?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

https://github.com/SheldonNeilson/Android-Alarm-Clock

I follow this example to write following code

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getApplicationContext(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hours, int minutes) {
    }
}, 1, 1, true);
timePickerDialog.setTitle("title");
timePickerDialog.show();
```

But this app will crash unless I use MyActivity.this instead of getApplicationContext()

It always use `getApplicationContext()` to replace `XXXX.this`, it was ok, but why this time is not ok?

How can I use TimePickerDialog without specifying current name of activity?

Because I will use it in Fragment, I tried `MyFragment.this` and `FragmentContainerActivity.this`, both of them cannot be used in this parameter

---

After open the dialog, I got this

[image: dialog1]

But it looks like this in the example program

[image: dialog2]

How can I make it same as example?

Comment: What android version does your device run?

Comment: dialog you getting is totally dependent on android version

Comment: But I run my programe and example in same device, I still got two different dialog, the android version is 4.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appearance will depends on the application theme also change the theme and check.

you try

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
```

Answer (score 0):

set theme for your timeDialog:

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getApplicationContext()
,R.style.mTimePickerStyle //your custom theme
,new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
...
```